# React onLoad img event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm writing a simple application that fetches a list of images as backgrounds (different sizes of the same image) and want to implement something like:

Small one loaded -> Set background, start fetching medium -> Medium loaded -> Set background, start fetching large

To accomplish this I'm setting a prefetch element, to load the image, and `onLoad`, set the background and start prefetching the next one.

According to [this](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/) article it should be as simple as:

```
<img src={image} alt="" onLoad={console.log('LOADED')}/>
```

And I should see a `LOADED` message *after* the image is completely loaded by the client.

That's not happening.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The `LOADED` message appears when the component mounts.

Comment: I'm throttling the network connection in Chrome to 'Fast 3g' the the time margin is significant.
I can clearly see the log coming while the image is still appearing one segment at the time

Comment: See my answer below. I think you're missing a lambda expression in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The problem**

You're missing an *arrow function expression*.
The direct call of the function will cause the `console.log()` to be fired as soon as the component is mounted. This is a common misconception, and is syntax related.

**What happens**

The function

`onLoad={console.log('LOADED')}`
is called as soon as the component is mounted, since you're actually calling the `console.log` not just setting up which `function` should be called when the event is fired, in this case the `onLoad`.

**How to fix it**

What you want to do is introduce an arrow function in there, so that you're calling the function when the `onLoad` is actually called.

`<img src={image} alt="" onLoad={() => console.log('LOADED')}/>`

You might also want to pass down event properties from the event. You can do this by introducing a variable for the event:

`<img onLoad={(event) => this.myHandleImageLoadEvent(event)} />`

Where the function `myHandleImageLoadEvent` is a function defined in the same class and has the event as an input parameter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on this? I'm not sure I understand what you're proposing. Sorry :(

Comment: Yes, look at my updated answer. It might be a different problem. Try using the lambda.

Comment: Worked like a charm. That was it.

Comment: Perfect. The same goes for `onClick` and all other events from a component. Remember to not call the function. If the event `onLoad` has some event properties you want to catch as well, you can use `onLoad={(event) => console.log(event)}` to pass the event object down to the console log method call. You can also call other methods the same way; `onLoad={(event) => this.handleOnLoad(event)}`

Comment: The term "lambda expression" is a .net specific term for a similar syntax. In JavaScript/ECMA Script they're called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)